# Prove that the $k^{th}$ derivative of $f$ has necessarily infinitely many zeros

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity

I have the following **question**: 
Let $f$ be a real entire function, i.e., $$f(x)=∑_{n=1}^{∞}a_{n}x^{n}$$

with infinitely many zeros.

Prove that the $k^{th}$ derivative of $f$ has necessarily infinitely many zeros for all $k≥1$.

Comment: That is a very unusual way to write a general entire function. Surely, there is a misprint?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I have rewrite the function as a power series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint** use the mean value theorem between adjacent zeroes, and induction

Comment: one could also argue by contradiction: suppose the conclusion is false, choose the smallest such $k$, and just show that 'infinitely many zeros' is conserved going from $k-1$ to $k$

Comment: the 'theorem' is true for $k=0$ as $f^{(0)}=f$

Comment: you're very welcome